# How to insert image in alert dialog builder

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Can I insert image in alert dialog builder? this is my code

```
public void Info(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Info Aplikasi");
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.info_adp);
    builder.setMessage("Jakarta Hospital Finder adalah " +
            "aplikasi pada perangkat mobile berbasis Android" +
            " yang memudahkan para pengguna untuk menemukan" +
            " lokasi serta menghubungi Rumah Sakit yang ada di daerah Jakarta.");
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Exit", null);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
    TextView messageView = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
    messageView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`AlertDialog.Builder` does not support adding an image using its API alone.  You must create a custom layout and add that to the builder in order to add an ImageView to the layout.  There is a very straight forward example in the official Alert Dialog documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout